# ffmpeg feeding mp4 file to rtsp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, kurento, ffserver

[image: ffserver.conf[![]]I am trying to feed a mp4 file from ffmpeg to rtsp stream using the command on centos 7:

from console 1: ffmpeg -i space.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -crf 18 http://localhost:8050/feed1.ffm

from console 2: I have started ffserver and it is started listening.

But when i open http://x.x.x.x:8050/feed1.ffm in browser it shows error:

**File ??feed1.ffm? not found**

My ffserver.conf file is attached

Answer (score 0):

Browser can't play RTSP directly so you need it delivered in a HTML5 format (HLS) that can load inside a VIDEO tag.
You can directly embed the mp4 inside a VIDEO tag if you wish.

FFMPEG needs to publish the video/stream to a streaming server that supports RTSP or the format you decide to publish as.

You can schedule mp4 videos to play as a live stream with this tool https://broadcastlivevideo.com/schedule-video-playlist-as-live-streaming-channel/ , available as free open source WP plugin.

Comment: Thank you but i just found out that i was using wrong file in url.